# Why tinyMCE.editors doesnt work on tinyMCE of wordpress

Tags: wordpress

```
<?php 
/*
Plugin Name: Taggr
Plugin URI: http://example.com/wordpress-plugins/my-plugin
Description: Premium plugin for image and photo tagging
Version: 1.0
Author: Tee Kai Yang
Author URI: http://wrox.com
License: GPLv2
*/


add_action('init', 'register_tagging_post');

//create taggr post type

 function register_tagging_post(){

       $tagging_args = array(
           'public' => true,
           'supports' => array(
               'title',
               'thumbnail'

           ), 
           'query_var' => 'tagging',
           'rewrite' => array(
              'slug' => 'taggr',
              'with_front' => false
           ),
            'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Taggr Albums',
            'singular_name' => 'Album',
            'add_new' => 'Add New Album',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New Album',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit Album',
            'new_item' => 'New Album',
            'view_item' => 'View Album',
            'search_items' => 'Search Albums',
            'not_found' => 'No Albums Found',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Albums Found In Trash'
        ),

        'menu_icon' => plugins_url() . '/taggr/images/PhotoAlbum.png',

        'menu_position' => 80, 

       );

       register_post_type('tagging', $tagging_args);


 }

    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'taggr_create_meta' );
 function taggr_create_meta(){

     add_meta_box( 'taggrMeta', 'Upload and edit photos/images', 'taggr_meta_function', 'tagging', 'normal', 'high' );

     function taggr_meta_function(){


     ?>

       <?php wp_editor("Enter your text", "my_editor"); ?>

    <script>
    window.onload = function(){
        alert(tinyMCE.editors[0].getContent());
    }
    </script>

        <?php

    }


    }


?>
```

Above is my code, I created a custom post and a tinyMCE text editor inside a metabox. But why when execute `alert(tinyMCE.editors[0].getContent());` line, it doesnt work and does not shows the content of the editors. The firebug shows the error of `TypeError: tinyMCE.editors[0] is undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You could provide your editors textarea's ID to get the content of the tinyMCE, also you should get the contents of the saved post meta and set it as the text of your editor element to display the value saved before. You could use the following code as a reference,

```
<?php
function taggr_meta_function($post){
 $my_editor = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_editor', true);
 wp_editor( $my_editor, "my_editor", array( 'textarea_name' => "my_editor" ) );
?>
   <script>
    window.onload = function(){
        alert(tinyMCE.get('my_editor').getContent());
    }
   </script>
<?php } ?>
```